# Deep ul - li list add class to all parents li from current tree using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this list:

```
<ul class="top">
    <li class="has-items">
        <a href="#">Link</a>    
        <ul>
            <li class="has-items">
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <ul>
                     <li class="active">
                         <a href="#">Link</a>
                     </li>   
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

When I set the current link parent `<li>` class to active, how can I add some other css class to all `li` parents from the current tree that have the class "has-items". Basically I want to add another css class `custom` for example, to all LI parents that have class has-items from the current tree so it will be like this:

```
<ul class="top">
    <li class="has-items custom">
        <a href="#">Link</a>    
        <ul>
            <li class="has-items custom">
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <ul>
                     <li class="active">
                         <a href="#">Link</a>
                     </li>   
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: How you set the `active` class? with click event?

Comment: actually is not on a click event cause there is post-back, but based on url i set the current link as active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
  $(this).parents("li.has-items").addClass("custom");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I want to add another css class custom for example, to all LI parents...

I assume you want something like this

```
 $(".active").parents('.has-items').addClass('custom');
```